# Forecasting with Kalman Filter with Exogenous Variables

Tags: statistics, time-series, kalman-filter

So I'm trying to forecast a Kalman Filter with exogenous variables in SAS but there doesn't seem to be a method that already does this so I'm coding it by myself. Since I'm no expert in the subject I decided to ask here. The problem is as follows:

I have an ARMA,

$x_t = a_1X_{t−1} + ... + a_kX_{t−m} + u_t + b_1u_{t−1} + ... + b_lu_{t−l}$

Thanks to Bent E. Sørensen in [https://uh.edu/~bsorense/kalman.pdf](https://uh.edu/%7Ebsorense/kalman.pdf),   I know that this process can be represented in the following State Space Form:

Transition equation:

$$\alpha_t = \begin{bmatrix}a_1&1&0&...&0\\a_2&0&1&...&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\a_{m-1}&0&0&...&1\\a_m&0&0&...&0\end{bmatrix} \alpha_{t-1} + \begin{bmatrix} 1\\b_1 \\ \vdots \\b_{m-2} \\ b_{m-1} \end{bmatrix} u_t$$

Measurement equation:

$$x_t = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&...&0\end{bmatrix}\alpha_t$$

Where $m=max{k,l+1}$. Now, by adding the exogenous variables,

$$x_t = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&...&0\end{bmatrix}\alpha_t + \Gamma v_t$$

Where,

$\hspace{1cm} \Gamma$ represents the unknown matrix of coefficients

$\hspace{1cm} v_t$ represents the vector of exogenous variables

So now the question is, how to estimate $\Gamma$ and, afterwards, forecast for $x_{t+1}$? Would be really grateful if someone could help or even point me in the right direction for the following steps.

Thanks in advance

PD: Sadly can't change the programming language, SAS is where I have to code it.

Comment: link for those who, like me, did not recognize "ARMA": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model

Comment: So the exogenous variables $v_t$ are known? And do you want to identify $\Gamma$ online (as the model runs, continuously try to improve your estimate of it) or try to fit it offline using a measurement series you collected from the system?

Comment: Yea, the exogenous variables are known and would prefer to identify $\Gamma$ online, so now that I look back at it, maybe would also have to identify the other coefficients online too...
Thanks!